# Unify multiple SQL rows

Tags: sql, oracle

For each `ids`, several names appear in several rows.
How can I make all of them appear in a single row?

```
select 
      cli.client, stb.macaddres, stb.unica as card, 
      pro.name 
from 
      clientes cli
inner join boxes stb on stb.nuclient = cli.nuclient
inner join date.servicio ser on ser.ids = stb.ids
inner join date.producto pro on pro.proid = ser.serid
where 
      cli.client=7;
```

Unexpected Results :

```
client macaddress  única  name
7       xxxxxxxxx  56565 product1
7       xxxxxxxxx  56565 product2
7       xxxxxxxxx  56565 product3
```

Desired Results :

```
client  macaddress  única  name
 7       xxxxxxxxx  56565 product1, product2,product3`
```

Comment: Hint:  `listagg()`.

Comment: Why? Who desires the results in that format? It can be done, but often that format is a sign of bad requirements or poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `listagg()` as gordon said in comment you can read here about documentation [**ListAGG()**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

And for your query :

```
select 
     cli.client, stb.macaddres, stb.unica as card 
     LISTAGG(pro.name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pro.proid ASC) "Name"
from 
     clientes cli
inner join boxes stb on stb.nuclient = cli.nuclient
inner join date.servicio ser on ser.ids = stb.ids
inner join date.producto pro on pro.proid = ser.serid
where 
     cli.client = 7;
Group By
    cli.client, stb.macaddres, stb.unica
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Gladly to help.. :)